# Rotate the phase of a wavelet

Tags: waves, rotation, phase-transition

Let's take a zero-phase [Ricker wavelet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_hat_wavelet) which is given by:

$$
\psi(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3\sigma}\pi^{1/4}}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{\sigma^2}\right)e^{-t^2/2\sigma^2}
$$
in the time domain which is often used in exploration seismology.
How can I determine the phase of this given wavelet and how can I rotate the phase of the wavelet by an angle $\theta$ ?

**UPDATE**

So if I rewrite the equation in terms of frequency I get this:

$$
x(t)=(1-2 \pi^2 f^2 t^2) e^{-\pi^2 f^2 t^2}
$$

How can I apply a phase rotation by $\Phi$ degrees? Like this?

$$
x(t)=(1-2 \pi^2 f^2 t^2) e^{(-\pi^2 f^2 t^2 - \Phi t)}
$$

Is this so difficult? I mean shifting a sine is pretty easy...

Comment: You could include your thoughts about it.

Comment: Do you mean rewriting the exponential part in terms of sinus aund cosinus? Or by using the instantaneus phase $\phi(t)=arg[\psi(t)]$?

Comment: Does it help if you write $(1-\frac{t^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})$ as $\exp(\log(1-\frac{t^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}))$?

Comment: I've no problem with the expression. I just did not fully understand how to phase rotate the wavelet. could you help me with that?